# How to provide a numerator to external software?

Tags: api

During a record creation from an external software (Using API) I need to get "The next value of a field"

I have the field set as a number, that starts from: 50000

I need to get that number, and than set that to: ++

- with programming langauge, I would set a Global Variable, and use it as: val = i++;

How can I achieve that in SF?

Can it be done without using APEX?

EDIT:

Since I have 2 flows that create the new object - one brings it's Own ID, while the other needs the system to create it, I can't add that field (I wish, that was my first try) to the object.

Also: I will NOT create a new record type for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you add an autonumber field to the target object?

This will be the least configuration / most reliable way I can think of.

---

edit

In response to your update, I have solved a similar problem before when we have one external system which generates its own id/key and another which requires the key to be generated by Salesforce.

You declare one text field as, let's call it "keycode". I'd make this unique and an external ID.

You declare a second field as an autonumber, let's call it "sf_sequence". For example "SF-00001"

You declare a workflow rule to run on creation and editing, with the criteria that it runs if the "keycode" is blank, and does a field update from  "sf_sequence" is copied into the "keycode"

Then when a record is inserted from the external system which maintains it's own ID, you store this value directly into "keycode". When the external system which doesn't have it's own ID inserts records, leave the value of "keycode" blank and salesforce will generate them from the autonumber via workflow.

Hope that helps.

Comment: See edited answer: I can't have that, since I have 2 flows to create the object.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution